# How to compare multidimensional arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, collections, compare

How to compare multidimensional arrays? Just true/false.

```cs
    double[,] data1 = new double[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };    
    double[,] data2 = new double[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
    
    //bool compare = data1.SequenceEqual(data2);
```

Is there way to compare 2d arrays like 1d array ?

```cs
    data1.SequenceEqual(data2);
```

I have to compare every second, so easiest way will be great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A multidimensional array can be used in linq as one dimensional enumerable. You just need to check also for the length of all dimensions. This snippet should be enough:

```cs
    var equal =
        data1.Rank == data2.Rank &&
        Enumerable.Range(0,data1.Rank).All(dimension => data1.GetLength(dimension) == data2.GetLength(dimension)) &&
        data1.Cast<double>().SequenceEqual(data2.Cast<double>());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can flat a multi-dimension array with `.Cast<String>`

```
Console.WriteLine("2D Array");
String[,] array2d = new String[,] { { "A1", "B1" }, { "A2", "B2" } };
foreach(var s in array2d.Cast<String>())
    Console.Write(s + ", ");

Console.WriteLine("\r\n3D Array");
String[,] array3d = new String[,] { { "A1", "B1", "C1" }, { "A2", "B2", "C1" } };
foreach (var s in array3d.Cast<String>())
    Console.Write(s + ", ");
```

## Output

```
2D Array
A1, B1, A2, B2, 
3D Array
A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C1,
```

Answer (score 3):

A generic extension method to compare 2D arrays:

```
public static bool SequenceEquals<T>(this T[,] a, T[,] b) => a.Rank == b.Rank
    && Enumerable.Range(0, a.Rank).All(d=> a.GetLength(d) == b.GetLength(d))
    && a.Cast<T>().SequenceEqual(b.Cast<T>());
```

Comment: Magic. Solved exactly the way I would do it, but faster.

Answer (score -8):

You can do this

```
data1.SequenceEqual(data2);
```

Comment: Multidimensional arrays do not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual'. I believe that's the reason why the author was looking for the answer to his question.